# xml document not validating to xsd schema

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd, schema

Working with eclipse I've got rid of all errors but when I alter the element contents in my xml document beyond what the restrictions are set as in the .xsd file no validation errors appear. I've tried validating it online with http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html and I get the error "Cvc-elt.1: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'DatabaseInventory'.. Line '4', Column '69'" yet in eclipse it validates fine. Not sure what I've done wrong.

This is my xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- standalone is no as this doc references external schema -->
<DatabaseInventory xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="DatabaseInventory.xsd">
<!-- tried to include "http://www.w3schools.com" alongside "DatabaseInventory.xsd" but      wouldn't validate  -->
<!-- default name space declaration -->
<!-- declare XML Schema Instance namespace, so schemaLocation attribute can be called -->
<!--  declare SYSTEM schema to use for this namespace "DatabaseInventory.xsd -->

  <DatabaseName>
    <GlobalDatabaseName>production.iDevelopment.info</GlobalDatabaseName>
    <OracleSID>Productio</OracleSID>
    <DatabaseDomain>iDevelopment.info</DatabaseDomain>
    <Administrator EmailAlias="jhunter" Extension="6007">
      Jeffrey Hunter
    </Administrator>
    <DatabaseAttributes Type="Production" Version="9i"/>
    <Comments>
      The following database should be considered the most stable for up-to-date 
      data. The backup strategy includes running the database in Archive Log Mode 
      and performing nightly backups. All new accounts need to be approved by the 
      DBA Group before being created.
    </Comments>
  </DatabaseName>

  <DatabaseName>
    <GlobalDatabaseName>development.iDevelopment.info</GlobalDatabaseName>
    <OracleSID>Development</OracleSID>
    <DatabaseDomain>iDevelopment.info</DatabaseDomain>
    <Administrator EmailAlias="jhunter" Extension="6007">
      Jeffrey Hunter
    </Administrator>
    <Administrator EmailAlias="mhunter" Extension="6008">
      Melody Hunter
    </Administrator>
    <DatabaseAttributes Type="Development" Version="9i"/>
    <Comments>
      The following database should contain all hosted applications. Production       
      data will be exported on a weekly basis to ensure all development environments        
      have stable and current data.
    </Comments>
  </DatabaseName>
<DatabaseName>
    <GlobalDatabaseName>testing.iDevelopment.info</GlobalDatabaseName>
    <OracleSID>Testing</OracleSID>
    <DatabaseDomain>iDevelopment.info</DatabaseDomain>
    <Administrator EmailAlias="jhunter" Extension="6007">
      Jeffrey Hunter
    </Administrator>
    <Administrator EmailAlias="mhunter" Extension="6008">
      Melody Hunter
    </Administrator>
    <Administrator EmailAlias="ahunter">
      Alex Hunter
    </Administrator>
    <DatabaseAttributes Type="Testing" Version="9i"/>
    <Comments>
      The following database will host more than half of the testing for our hosting 
      environment.
    </Comments>
  </DatabaseName>

</DatabaseInventory>
```

This is the schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 

<!-- using Venetian blinds layout, s3346141 - 1 mod 3 = 1 -->

<xs:complexType name="DatabaseAttributes-type">
    <xs:attribute name="Type" type="restricted-Type-values" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Version" type="restricted-Version-values" default="9i"/>
    <!--  set default value for Version -->
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="restricted-Extention-values">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="6[0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
      <!-- set REGEX for first digit = 6 followed by 3 digits -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="restricted-Type-values">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Production"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Development"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Testing"/>
      <!--  converted enumerated list into discrete values--> 
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="restricted-Version-values">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="7"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="8i"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="9i"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>


<xs:simpleType name="max-string-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="300"/> 
            <!-- increased char length to 300 to enable validation of DatabaseInventory.xml -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="Administrator-type">
<!--  felt I needed to discriminate a name difference between element names and repeated types to make code clearer -->
  <xs:attribute name="EmailAlias" type="xs:string" use = "required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Extension" type="restricted-Extention-values" use = "optional"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DatabaseName-type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="GlobalDatabaseName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="OracleSID" type="restricted-Type-values" />
            <xs:element name="DatabaseDomain" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Administrator-type" type="Administrator-type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
            <xs:element name="DatabaseAttributes" type="DatabaseAttributes-type" />
            <xs:element name="Comments" type="max-string-type" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DatabaseInventory-type">
<xs:sequence>
 <xs:element name="DatabaseName" type="DatabaseName-type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 <!-- set databaseName element to occur 1 or more times -->
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>    

<xs:element name="DatabaseInventory" type="DatabaseInventory-type" />
<!-- set root element to link to DatabaseInventory-type -->
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, eclipse doesn't perform any validation, since it cannot associate a schema with the instance document.

First, your schema does not specify a target namespace, which means that your instance document should *not* declare the default namespace:

```
<DatabaseInventory xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" >
```

Change that to:

```
<DatabaseInventory >
```

Second, the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute takes a list of `{URI, URL}` pairs, where URI is the namespace URI and URL the location of the corresponding schema. However, since your schema does not declare a target name space, you should instead use the  `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute. Your first element should look like this:

```
<DatabaseInventory 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="DatabaseInventory.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two things wrong.
1. -You have this in the schema:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="restricted-Type-values">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
 <xs:enumeration value="Production"/>
 <xs:enumeration value="Development"/>
 <xs:enumeration value="Testing"/>
 <!--  converted enumerated list into discrete values--> 
 </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

And this in the XML:

```
<OracleSID>Productio</OracleSID>
```

and must be

```
<OracleSID>Production</OracleSID>
```

which is one of the valid values.

2.- You have this element in your XML:

```
<Administrator EmailAlias="jhunter" Extension="6007">
```

but is not defined in your XSD. Maybe you wanted to use this other element:

```
<xs:element name="Administrator-type" type="Administrator-type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
```

So you must replace this:

```
    <Administrator EmailAlias="jhunter" Extension="6007">
       Jeffrey Hunter
    </Administrator>
```

with this

```
    <Administrator-type EmailAlias="jhunter" Extension="6007">
        Jeffrey Hunter
    </Administrator-type>
```